# Does the geometric mean of p-values have a meaning?

Tags: statistics, mean, p-value

I use two methods, each of them yielding a p-value:

```
p1
p2
```

Given that these methods are different and complementary, I would combine their p-values in a geometric mean:

```
p=sqrt( p1 * p2 )
```

although I am pretty sure there are much more rigorous ways to achieve that combination, I aim first at an intuitive and easy way.

Nevertheless, does such a mean of p-values make sense?

I precise, that I am interested in the *ranking* of events relative to their p-values, more than in their absolute values.

Cheers,
Xavier

Answer (score 1):

I think you can answer this for yourself if you think it through. A p-value is `p(data | something)` where `something` is some combination of model, parameters, and hypothesis. What is `sqrt(p(data | something) p(data | something else))` ? Is there a general law of probability which will enable you to derive some other expression from that?

Comment: My guess was that it could be interpreted as "probability of A AND B" is prob(A) * prob(B), like in the definition of the likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

If the methods are very independent, then the Fisher's method offers a simple way to combine p values:
http://mikelove.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/combining-p-values-fishers-method-sum-of-p-values-binomial/
which is somehow related to the geometrical mean.